# Disabling Eclipse auto-complete but keeping auto-activation

Tags: java, eclipse, intellisense

I use Eclipse for Java development. I like the auto-activation feature because I can add all the letters and numbers so I can see class members while I'm typing; making it behave similarly to Visual Studio. If I don't add all of the letters and numbers to the auto-activation list, it will only pop up with class information when I'm typing the first letter after the '.' delimiter, and then it disappears.

The real problem arises when I'm typing in a variable name or something else. As soon as I hit space, the auto-complete types a bunch of crap following what I've typed in attempt to complete it. It's driving me crazy!

Any way to turn this off?

Comment: I hesitate to ask... did you accidentally put a space in the autoactivation list?

Comment: I don't know why they designed eclipse to act this way. I can type faster than I can pick something out of the autocomplete list. I just want the context help.

Comment: The autocomplete is terrible too, it seems like it just picks a random function to autofill when you type "(" then I have to always go back and fix it because it is never fight.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT**: It seems this answer is now outdated. It may work for old Eclipse versions. For any more recent versions refer to @ChrisP's answer from 2019.

Open menu *Window*, then *Preferences*. Follow path *Java -> Editor -> Content assist*. Now mess around with the settings to find your ideal setup. I believe what you'll want is to deactivate *Insert single proposals automatically*.

Comment: That works. Thanks. That was one of the few checkboxes I hadn't messed with.

Comment: Did not work for me. "insert single proposals automatically" was already disabled. Enabling "disable insertion triggers except enter" did the trick for me.

Comment: This answer is 9 years old by now and I haven't used Eclipse in years. Likely the settings have changed. Rather than downvoting it would have been preferable to note that a newer answer is now more accurate so I can delete or edit this one.

Answer (score 20):

The checkbox you have to check is: "**Disable insertion triggers exept 'Enter'** "

(under *Java -> Editor -> Content assist*)

I'm on Eclipse 2018-12 and C_H's answer had no effect on the behavior:

> I believe what you'll want is to deactivate "Insert single proposals automatically"

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, thanks!

Comment: that is the solution that i was looking for all this day! thanks

Answer (score 5):

If anyone wants to know how to stop the auto-complete for **brackets**:

Toggle off: **"Edit --> Smart Insert Mode"**
[image]

Version: Eclipse Photon

Answer (score 0):

In continuation to @G_H's answer :
This worked for me although I am sure there is another and a better way.

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Set Auto Activation Delay(ms) : 200ms from 0ms in my case.
You may want to increase/decrease the value 200 depending on your typing speed.

The reason this worked is because of the hitting of "Spacebar" before the delay arrives.